# What IOS version Flutter Ffmpeg at least

Tags: dart, flutter

I am working on some Flutter demo project in which I have to get metadata from a video file and save it in a variable. I have used FFmpeg but it is taking around 20 seconds for a 6 minute video(ffmpeg.getMediaInformation()). Is there any way I can get the metadata instantly, and save it in a variable?

Also, I need to know which is the minimum target version of IOS Flutter FFmpeg Supports.

Answer (score 0):

platform :ios, '9.3' definition to your ios/Podfile file.